# I want to stop using "I" vs I want to stop to use "I"

Tags: grammar

I looked for Cambridge dictionary to know the difference between stop-verb-ing form and stop-to-infinitive.

> We use the -ing form after stop to indicate that an action or event is no longer continuing:
>
> We use the to-infinitive after stop to indicate that someone stops doing something in order to do something else:

So here's my quesiton.

> *I want to stop **using** "I" at beginning of sentence*.

vs

> *I want to stop **to use** "I" at beginning of sentence*.

(When I start to speak and write in English, I always express that "I am, I was, I can," and who know what else any other verbs. It make me that I feel like that I always try to introduce myself.)

Comment: What is unclear about the quoted text?

Comment: They are clear but I don't know when I say that "I want to stop using or I want to stop to use" about the difference. Which is more natural

Comment: The second one is funny because consider this: I want to stop to get some food. So, your second sentence would therefore mean: You want to stop [doing something] so you can use "I" at the beginning of a sentence...

Answer (score 2):

The rules you quote may be clearer with examples:

> We use the -ing form after stop to indicate that an action or event is no longer continuing:
>
> > John stopped running. ... *means that John had been running but then stopped*
>
> We use the to-infinitive after stop to indicate that someone stops doing something in order to do something else:"
>
> > John stopped to catch his breath. ... *means that John had been doing something else but then stopped so he could catch his breath.*

The two can in fact be combined:

> John stopped running to catch his breath. ... *means that John had been running but then stopped running so he could catch his breath.*

So what you want to say is:

> I want to stop using *I* at the beginning of sentences.